# jquery applying css class on select on radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

i have 3 radio buttons.what i need to do is that when one radio button is selected so i need to apply my css class name "line" on the text after it like

```
  <span> <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk">  Milk </span>
```

i need to apply my class on Milk
and when user select other radio button so the same class apply on other radio button text but remove class from the previous one.this is what i tried

```
<style type="text/css">
    .line{
        text-decoration: line-through;
         }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked'))
          //i wana do this
           $(this).addClass('line');
         //if another is selected so do this
           $(this).removeClass('line');
      });
   });
```

```
 <div>
  <span> <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk">  Milk </span> </br>
  <span> <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Butter"> Butter </span> </br>
  <span> <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Cheese"> Cheese </span> </br>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need to add the class to the `span`, you can use [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to access the `span` from the radio button. To remove the class from the other `span` elements, just remove it from all which have the class in question before adding the class to the `span` that was just selected:

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
   if(this.checked) {
      $('span.line').removeClass('line');
      $(this).parent().addClass('line');
   }
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6B7sS/).

Note the use of `this.checked` instead of the jQuery version you had. It is much faster to use the native DOM property where possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
    console.log(this.checked)
    if (this.checked) {
        // remove previously added line class
        $('span.line').removeClass('line');
        // you should add class to span, because text is
        // within span tag, not in input
        $(this).parent().addClass('line');
    }
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/n2Jcm/2/)**